# Passing parameter to class property in Java

Tags: java, android, class, parameters, getter-setter

I have this property in a visual basic class. NET 2008, the property in addition to the get and set has a parameter called "pParam. "

```
Public Property UpdateField(ByVal pParam As String) As String
        Get
            Return Me.idField
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.idField = value
            If pParam = "NEW" Then
        // some code here
            End If
        End Set
End Property
```

which is the equivalent of this in java code?

to use I do the following:

```
oClass.UpdateField("NEW") = 1850
```

I have this code in java

```
public void setUpdateField(String idField) {
    this.idField = idField;
}
public String getUpdateField() {
    return idField;
}
```

but I need to put the parameter "pParam"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do with pParam?  Isn't it just asking in set if the field equals some value?  So you could just do `if (idField.equals("NEW"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got in the .NET code is an *indexer* in C# terms. There's no equivalent in Java - you'll just need to take two parameters:

```
public void setUpdateField(String idField, String pParam) {
    ...
}
```

Frankly I think it's a little odd that the "getter" in .NET doesn't seem to use the index...